# Sharing On Tumber in iOs,want ot share both image and text?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios4, tumblr

I have searched a lot on "Sharing On tumbler" but still i am not getting any valuable thing that sort my problem.
If you have any idea about which API should used and how do i share on tumblr so please share your knowledge with me..

if you have any tutorial or any source code or any idea still share it with me...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
- (BOOL)sendPhotoToTumblr:(NSString *)photo usingEmail:(NSString *)tumblrEmail andPassword:(NSString *)tumblrPassword withCaption:(NSString *)caption;
{
    //get image data from file
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photo];  
    //stop on error
    if (!imageData) return NO;

    //Create dictionary of post arguments
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"password",@"type",@"caption",nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            tumblrEmail,
            tumblrPassword,
            @"photo", caption, nil];
    NSDictionary *keysDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    //create tumblr photo post
    NSURLRequest *tumblrPost = [self createTumblrRequest:keysDict withData:imageData];
    [keysDict release];     

    //send request, return YES if successful
    tumblrConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:tumblrPost delegate:self];
    if (!tumblrConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
        return NO;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Request submitted");
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            [tumblrConnection release];
        return YES;
    }
}


-(NSURLRequest *)createTumblrRequest:(NSDictionary *)postKeys withData:(NSData *)data
{
    //create the URL POST Request to tumblr
    NSURL *tumblrURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/api/write"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *tumblrPost = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tumblrURL];
    [tumblrPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Add the header info
    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    [tumblrPost addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //create the body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //add key values from the NSDictionary object
    NSEnumerator *keys = [postKeys keyEnumerator];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [postKeys count]; i++) {
        NSString *tempKey = [keys nextObject];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",tempKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[postKeys objectForKey:tempKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    //add data field and file data
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //add the body to the post
    [tumblrPost setHTTPBody:postBody];

    return tumblrPost;
}
```

Code based on http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513

Comment: I have used your code but i am getting response as Authentication fail. which email/password should pass there. or have to pass any other thing ... please help.